# Rails ActiveRecord sum of stars for second attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to display in view which rateable_id has the most stars.count for "dimension: foundation"?

This is in my table rates:

```
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 11
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:23.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 12
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:24.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 13
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:25.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 14
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:26.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 15
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:33:27.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 16
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:30.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 17
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 18
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:31.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 19
    rater_id: 1
    rateable_id: 5
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 5.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:32.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 25
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: foundation
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:46.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 26
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: originality
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:49.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 27
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: dynamics
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:51.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 28
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: execution
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:53.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Rate
  attributes:
    id: 29
    rater_id: 8
    rateable_id: 3
    rateable_type: Bboy
    stars: 1.0
    dimension: battle
    created_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-03-04 14:06:54.000000000 Z
```

This is in my tabke bboys:

```
- !ruby/object:Bboy
  attributes:
    id: 3
    name: taisuke
    crew: japan
    country: JAP
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:32:56.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:32:56.000000000 Z
    avatar_file_name: justdoit.jpeg
    avatar_content_type: image/jpeg
    avatar_file_size: 9297
    avatar_updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:32:55.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Bboy
  attributes:
    id: 4
    name: roxrite
    crew: us
    country: us
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:35:40.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:35:40.000000000 Z
    avatar_file_name: 
    avatar_content_type: 
    avatar_file_size: 
    avatar_updated_at: 
- !ruby/object:Bboy
  attributes:
    id: 5
    name: me
    crew: japan
    country: JAP
    created_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:23.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-02-25 09:36:23.000000000 Z
    avatar_file_name: justdoit.png
    avatar_content_type: image/png
```

Thank you for your time and expertise! You are helping me out a 1000!

Answer (score 1):

This two-step  solution will probably work:

```
most_starred_id = Rate.where(dimension: 'foundation').select("rateable_id, sum('stars') as total_stars").group(:rateable_id).order(:total_stars => :desc).first.rateable_id

most_starred = Bboy.find(most_starred).name
```

Comment: Hi there, Could u pls have a look at my rails problem on this new post. Any feedback is greatly appreciated! link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840627/rails-activerecord-model-sorting-how